# Do we need the [checklist] tag. If so, what is it about?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, tag-wiki

I just reviewed [checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklist) for plagiarised content. It turned out to have a tag wiki that had nothing to do with programming, but more how people use checklists in daily life.

> **Checklist**
>   A checklist is a type of informational job aid used to reduce failure by compensating for potential limits of human memory and attention. It helps to ensure consistency and completeness in carrying out a task.

There are 101 posts with this tag. Looking at the questions under this tag, it is unclear what this tag is supposed to refer to.

Do we need the checklist tag, if so what is it about?

Comment: One to check off the list.

Comment: @Paulie_D off the tag list?

Comment: I would...if it's unclear it's of little use...[burniate]

Comment: @Paulie_D do I turn this into a burniate request?

Comment: Let's see what the consensus is...but it seems a reasonable course.

Comment: Do we need a [checklist]?

Comment: Add to the [burnination][checklist]? ;)

Comment: Burninate [checklist] -- *Check* (once it's done, obviously)

Comment: [checklist] checking out

Comment: Burninate this off your [checklist].

Comment: Take this off your [checklist].

Comment: +1 for burninate of [checklist]

Comment: [checklist] × or ✓?

Comment: It’s just great how the comments are only about finding the best burniation pun…

Comment: @poke but isn't it nice just to have pure fun? :D

Comment: I wasn’t saying it it is a bad thing ;P I’m just amazed how *that’s* the important thing here to discuss :D

Comment: I agree. Unlike [tag:checkbox] or [tag:list], there's no pre-made "check list" construct in programming, to my knowledge (or as far as the tag wiki is concerned, either), and it's clearly not a popular or obvious tagging choice. This one's safe to burninate.

Comment: Uncheck [checklist]

Comment: The ultimate burnination [checklist]

Comment: Though that may be confusing for users actually looking for a burnination checklist...

Comment: @TinyGiant yes and there's questions pretty much like that

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklist) tag has been burniated.

Answer (score -8):

A checklist (sometimes called a checkbox list) is a type of visual control where multiple items are presented, and the user can check or uncheck the individual items. The current questions that are tagged [checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklist) that I went through are indeed about such a control.

We have tags about specific types of visual controls. We have [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button), [checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkbox), [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview), [menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menubar), [drop-down-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu), [radio-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/radio-group), probably many more. Such tags make a lot of sense for searching for relevant questions when combined with UI framework tags. I don't see any reason why [checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklist) should be removed.

That said, if you feel that "checklist" is a wrong name, then I don't see a problem with retagging the questions to use a better name. It's just removing it entirely that I don't see as a good option.

Comment: I can't see an actual `checklist` control in any of the languages, can you please provide an example? If so, we can add that to the wiki, only to be used with [tag:language], or [tag:platform]. From what I can see there are checkbox-lists and things similar, but not an actual checklist. There are lists that can have check boxes, as you said. I think it's important to stick with the actual names of the controls.

Comment: @MsYvette It's inconsistent, sure. ASP.NET calls it a [`CheckBoxList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Delphi calls it a [`TCheckListBox`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.CheckLst.TCheckListBox). But there are JQuery [dropdown check list](https://code.google.com/archive/p/dropdown-check-list/) and [`dialog`](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807)'s `--checklist` option.

Comment: none of those are actually a checklist. I think it's better to have the tags with the correct control name to avoid confusion. there's no reason we can't have a [tag:dropdownchecklist] and in the wiki instruct that it be used with jquery, [tag;TCheckListBox] instructing it be used with delphi and so on. As it stands I removed 40 ish posts from the tag and they were from all sorts of languages and many questions are asking for a checklist as in a to do list when programming for the programmer to follow. So not at all appropriate.

Comment: @MsYvette Er... what? In what way aren't they a checklist? If you mean the name, that's why I included the last one, where the name is exactly `checklist`, nothing else. For the second-to-last one, the reason it's called dropdown check list is the dropdown and checklist combination. The other ones are just check lists without the dropdown aspect. [tag:dropdownchecklist] would be highly inappropriate for them.

Comment: @hvd [Checklist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checklist) in English refers to a list of items to be completed/obtained/etc. So "checklist" refers not only to a type of visual element but also the the *purpose* of that visual element. A list with checkboxes attached could serve an entirely different purpose, such as a list of options where the user can choose multiple items or a set of questions with yes/no answers.