# Do we need tags for UI elements?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today a user decided to start removing a tag for a specific UI element ([checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklist)). The community seems to be in support of its removal. I'm not, not even remotely, but I do think the community should decide.

I do not see any relevant distinction between this and e.g. [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview), [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button), [menubar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/menubar), etc. What's the community's stance on this? Do we want tags for UI elements? Do we want to burninate the whole lot? Are some UI elements more important than others? If so, what makes them so?

---

To prevent miscommunication, let me be precise about my question. I see multiple possibilities and I have no idea about what the community consensus might be. In an answer, can you please explain which of these you are proposing?

1. [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button), [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview), [checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklist) all shouldn't exist. We should burninate them all.
2. [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button), [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview), [checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklist) all shouldn't exist. It's not worth burninating them all though.
3. [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button), [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview), [checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklist) all should exist.
4. [button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/button), [listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/listview) should exist, but [checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checklist) shouldn't.
5. Other.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316057/do-we-need-the-checklist-tag-if-so-what-is-it-about

Comment: Can someone be an expert in checklist?

Comment: @Will As much as someone can be an expert in listviews, buttons and menubars, don't you think?

Comment: Nope.  I wouldn't know jack squat about buttons in Swift, but you need to push a button on a webpage or a WPF application?  I got your back.

Comment: @Will And I don't know a whole lot about Delphi's `TCheckListBox` (it's been years since I last even saw it), but you can ask me about ASP.NET's `CheckBoxList`. So what's the difference? Why should buttons have a tag, but checklists/checkbox lists/check listboxes not? Or should buttons not have a tag, or should a tag for checklists/checkbox lists/check listboxes be reinstated?

Comment: None of them should have tags, imho.  They're just too meta-y.  Meaty?  Metaish?  Anyhow, stuff.

Comment: @Will That would be a perfectly valid and acceptable answer. Can you post it as such? The goal of my question here is to get the community's input, and posting your answer allows the community to vote to indicate agreement or disagreement.

Comment: Most of my software work is embedded and I occasionally have to deal with a whole range of different types of physical button.  Should I tag any questions regarding de-bouncing electronic contacts with a `Button` tag?

Comment: @MikeofSST According to the tag description, no, you shouldn't.

Comment: It's pretty well covered by other answers.  If you upvote Braiam and downvote TrueEddie, you arrive at my comment.

Comment: @Will Braiam only gave a partial answer, but Mike of SST did post a complete answer later that agrees with your comment.

Answer (score 16):

It would appear that all tags relating to UI elements should all be burninated as being meta tags.  According to the criteria in [Jeff Atwood's blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) they fail on both counts:

- The tags makes no sense on their own, since the UI framework is almost certainly necessary for any question containing such a tag to met the usual standards for a question.
- List View, Button, Menu Bar and Check List can all be interpreted in different ways depending on your background and experience.

There are many framework-specific tags for UI controls that do not fail the meta-tag tests.  Since SO requires questions to be specific, why should tags not follow the same rule?

Answer (score 7):

In how many ways can you implement a "checklist"? For your programming language, what is a "checklist"? Is this even a programming context? For me the answers are: many, whatever I decide, and no. Checklists are basically what you want to make them. For example:

- This is a check list
- It may not be for you, but for me it is

  - I'm sorry
- I think you got the idea
- YAY

For you, without checkboxes it may not be a checklist, or whatever you fancy. This is not important for programmers. If your question is "Why doesn't this HTML check box update my JSON object when creating a checklist?", the mention of "checklist" is at best tangential or at worst totally irrelevant for the problem you are facing. We create tags for stuff intrinsically related to programming.

Comment: The "checklist" tag was removed without a replacement even for questions that were specifically about such a UI element (not something custom that looks sort of like it). I agree that the tag would be inappropriate in your example, but that's not what I'm asking about, so this really doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @hvd if you replace "checklist" with "UI elements" they are equivalent, don't you agree?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. If you replace "checklist" where?

Comment: @hvd in my answer.

Comment: And what is supposed to then be equivalent? "Checklist" and "UI element"? No, definitely not, in the same way that even though a button is a UI element, "button" is not equivalent to / synonymous with "UI element".

Comment: @hvd a myriad of elements working together to obtain a "checklist" vs a myriad of elements working together to obtain an UI, seems equivalent.

Comment: An example of a single UI element is ASP.NET's `CheckBoxList` class, where the programmer works with that class and does *not* create any individual `CheckBox` controls. For questions about such controls, a checklist or checkboxlist tag makes perfect sense to me. Yet a tag was deemed inappropriate even for such questions.

Comment: I've expanded my question to hopefully be a bit clearer. I'm not sure whether your answer is my item 1, 2 or 4.

Comment: @hvd ugh, that looks like an overkill class. What was the problem with allowing people to define how the data was stored, create a helper function that interacts with the data and creates the checkboxes with all the fluff? Granted, there may be limitations ot ASP.NET that don't allow this, but I'm kind of ol' school "Do One Thing and Do It Well".

Comment: That could be a different interesting discussion, but it's one not really suitable for Meta. :)

Answer (score -1):

I see their value when paired with other tags.  For instance if I need help with a WPF Button vs an HTML Button.  This way I can get help for the specific UI element within a specific framework.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I've expanded my question since I see your answer as open to interpretation. Can you take another look and elaborate?

Comment: If that's true, it would make them meta-tags, and therefore firm candidates for burnination.  There are plenty of framework-specific alternatives for most controls.